# How to stop moving cursor but be able to understand where the cursor would be at if the code wasn't working in Python?

Tags: python, mouse

I think it is a bit difficult to explain but I'll try. Basically, I need to prevent the mouse to move but be able to track it.

For example, when I move mouse for 10 pixel, cursor moves 10 pixel normally. However, I want the cursor to stay in the same position and want the code to print "Mouse would be at x+10, y if it wasn't locked.".

I am sorry if it wasn't clear enough. But, please help me I don't have any other information or idea. By the way, I don't want the cursor to be moved to the start point again and again. Because this doesn't actually stop the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question!) That's what I managed to find thanks to personal interest.

The [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library contains tools for [monitoring](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse) mouse events, and also makes it possible to implement your own callbacks that will fire on certain events (just like implementing a function that will be executed on the onClick event in javascript).

Another useful property of this tool is this flag:

> **suppress** (bool) – Whether to suppress events. Setting this to True
> will prevent the input events from being passed to the rest of the
> system.

With it, you can literally intercept all mouse movement events, handle them, while not allowing the mouse to actually move.

However, due to the fact that the mouse doesn't really move in the end, you have to calculate its possible position manually, saving previous state between events.

To make sure my solution was correct, I decided to use the turtle to draw the path of an imaginary mouse, and it turned out pretty accurate (although sometimes the mouse behaves a little strange, so this code is definitely not perfect, but may lead you to a more accurate answer).

In the end, this code actually stops the mouse completely, and actually predicts its position "if it hadn't been stopped". It looks something like this, if visualized:
[image: Visualization of cursor position prediction]

Code itself (you can remove all parts of the code related to drawing in order to get only the calculation of coordinates):

```py
from pynput import mouse
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# please enter your screen resolution
SCREEN_SIZE = (2560, 1440)
DRAW_TURTULE = True


class Tracker:
    def __init__(self, screen_size):
        self.start_x, self.start_y = None, None
        self.curr_x, self.curr_y = None, None
        self.max_x, self.max_y = screen_size

        # drawing part
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.screen.screensize(self.max_x, self.max_y)
        self.screen.setworldcoordinates(0, self.max_y, self.max_x, 0)

        self.yertle = Turtle("turtle")
        self.yertle.speed("fastest")

    def move(self, x, y):
        # if this first time the mouse is moved, initialize the start position
        if self.start_x is None:
            print("Started at {0}".format((x, y)))
            self.start_x, self.start_y = x, y
            self.curr_x, self.curr_y = x, y
            return

        # take x and y difference from the start position
        # add that or subtract that from the current position
        # max and min needed to make sure the pointer doesn't go out of the screen
        self.curr_x = min(self.max_x, max(0, self.curr_x + (x - self.start_x)))
        self.curr_y = min(self.max_y, max(0, self.curr_y + (y - self.start_y)))

        positionStr = f"Pointer would be at ({self.curr_x:4}, {self.curr_y:4})"
        print(positionStr, end="")
        print("\b" * len(positionStr), end="", flush=True)

        # drawing part
        self.yertle.goto(self.curr_x, self.curr_y)

    # click to stop program
    def click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        print("\n{0} at {1}".format("Pressed" if pressed else "Released", (x, y)))
        if not pressed:
            # Stop listener
            return False

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.mainloop()


t = Tracker(SCREEN_SIZE)

if DRAW_TURTULE:
    # Collect events until released (clicked) NON BLOCKING
    listener = mouse.Listener(on_move=t.move, on_click=t.click, suppress=True)
    listener.start()

    t.draw()
else:
    # Collect events until released (clicked) BLOCKING (syncronous)
    with mouse.Listener(on_move=t.move, on_click=t.click, suppress=True) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been stuck because of this problem for a long time.